# How does tensorflow handle quantized networks

Tags: tensorflow

I have been reading about tensorflow's conversion of neural networks from floats to 8 bit values. Reading the matrix multiplication code in  their repository seems to indicate that they are using 8 bit integers rather than fixed floating point which their documentation might have indicated.

I want to understand how exactly it performs the transformation. From what I have read, Am guessing that it scales the weights from 0 to 255. For instance, if we are talking about convolution on an input image which has a range of 0 to 255. The result of the convolution would then be a 32 bit integers which are then scaled back to 0 to 255 using statistics of min and max of the output. Is that correct ?

If so, Why does this work ?

Repository I checked for their code
https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/standalone/neon-gemm-kernel-benchmark.cc#L573

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization this is what led me to believe tensorflow is using fixed point

Comment: "Why does this work" for the min/max scheme at https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization seems too vague to answer. I guess fundamentally the extra bits often used in floating point formats aren't necessary, and fixing the exponent seems not to hurt performance in practice. Is there some reason you think it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm one year late to answer this question, but this answer may help someone else

### Quantization

First, Quantization is the process of converting a continuous range of values (float numbers) to a finite range of discrete values (quantized integers `qint`). Quantized datatypes are pretty common with embedded systems because most embedded systems have limited resources and to load a trained network (that could be more than 200 MB) on a microcontroller is unachievable. So, we have to find out a way to reduce the size of these trained networks.

Almost all of the size of trained neural networks is taken up with the weights. Because all of the weights are floating-point numbers, simple compression formats like zip don’t compress them well. So, we had to find another way which is “Quantization”.

### How is done?

Quantization is done by storing the minimum value and the maximum value for each layer's weights and then compressing each float value to an eight-bit integer representing the closest real number.

For example, assume that the weights of a certain layer in our neural network vary from -4.85 to 2.35 which represent the min and max respectively. Then quantization is done using the following formula:

[image]

Then, for example, the number 1.3 and 0 will be:

[image]

This simple formula can get the size to shrink by 75%, and as you can see, it’s reversible if we want to convert it back to float after loading so that your existing floating-point code can work without any changes. Moving calculations over to eight-bit will make trained models run faster, and use less power which is essential on embedded systems and mobile devices.

### Quantization Vs Precision

Won’t that affect the precision of the model? Apparently, its effect isn’t that big and in this [article](https://petewarden.com/2015/05/23/why-are-eight-bits-enough-for-deep-neural-networks/) we can see why. But in short, when we are trying to teach a network, the aim is to have it understand the patterns and discard noise. That means we expect the network to be able to produce good results despite a lot of noise. The networks that emerge from this process have to be very robust numerically, with a lot of redundancy in their calculations so that small differences in input samples don’t affect the results. And that’s what makes neural networks robust when it comes to noise. So, we can consider the quantization error as some kind of noise that well-trained neural networks can handle.